# How do you declare a custom structure to retain field values after a scene reload?

Tags: unity, scene, struct

I have the following code :

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 Vector3;
    public Foo Foo;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Foo = new Foo(1);
    }
}
```

After scene is reloaded, the value of the field inside `Foo` is lost (reset to the default value which in this case is zero), while fields inside `Vector3` (which is a built-in type in Unity) are kept.

Foo is defined this way:

```
public struct Foo
{
     public int x;

     public Foo(int x)
     {
         this.x = x;
     }
}
```

How to modify that structure to make it behave like `Vector3` after scene is reloaded ? (the value inside fields are kept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your struct to be serializable:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public struct Foo {
   // ...
}
```

This tells Unity to record the values of its fields marked `public` or `[SerializeField]` into scene or prefab asset files that contain this structure. If the type does not have this attribute, the C# compiler doesn't generate the helpers needed to serialize and deserialize it to/from a data stream this way.

This will not, on its own, save and restore values that changed while playing in a scene. Reloading the scene will restore the values saved in the `.unity` scene file, ie. the last values it had at edit time. If you want to store values somewhere that won't get unloaded/reloaded on scene changes, you can use a `static` variable to hold data not attached to any single instance.

Comment: It seems a additional requirement for serialization to occur correctly is the field to not be readonly (even if public)

Comment: Yep, that's part of the definition of readonly: a field that can only be written to in a field initializer or a constructor. A deserializer is neither a field initializer nor a constructor, so it cannot write a value to a readonly field.

Comment: Do you know what can cause a scene to be "reloaded" ? I found the issue discussed here when using profiler and enabling "deep profile" mode (which trigger scene reload).

Comment: Entering and exiting play mode, unloading the scene via the `SceneManager`, or triggering an assembly reload by changing C# scripts (that's what the deep profile does — it changes your code to compile-in profiling hooks, then needs to load the serialized content against the revised code).